# How to use backup MySQL files files on a volume instead of default

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, disk-volume

I have a server hosted on Scaleway with multiple staging sites on.

I accidentally archived the server instead of turning it off which means the MySQL data for my websites is currently stored in `/mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql` however MySQL is currently looking at `/var/lib/mysql` therefore none of my databases are being picked up.

How can I get MySQL to look at the path to the MySQL data on the volume instead?

I have tried following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04

However when it comes to starting MySQL up again, I get:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with
error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe"
for details.
```

And running `systemctl status mysql` gives:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-06-28 17:53:13 UTC; 2s ago
  Process: 16742 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 16734 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16742 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 16743 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─16743 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─16751 sleep 1
```

I would try moving the contents of `/mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql` to `/var/lib/mysql` however as far as I understand, if I did I would run out of space on the server

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           1010M     0 1010M   0% /dev
tmpfs           203M   29M  175M  14% /run
none           1012M  845M  168M  84% /
tmpfs          1012M     0 1012M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1012M     0 1012M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nbd0        46G   46G     0 100% /mnt/volume0
/dev/nbd1        92G   41G   47G  47% /mnt/volume
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need a temporary solution:

```
mount -o bind /mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Or in MySQL, in /etc/my.cnf you need to change [datadir](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_datadir) to point to new folder. E.g.  `datadir=/mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql`. Make sure /mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql is writable.

Comment: Thanks Mircea, I have given your second option a try but i'm getting

`[Warning] Can't create test file /mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql/passionstaging.lower-test

[ERROR] failed to set datadir to /mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql/`

When trying to start up mysql. I think this is probably related to mysql not having write access to the directory.

Here is the permissions on the directory

`drwx------ 77 sshd            syslog             4096 Jun 28 14:31 mysql/`

Could you provide some guidance on how to change the permissions correctly? Do I need to change permissions recursively?

Thanks!

Comment: The folder and files should be accessible for the user that MySQL is running as. Usually this is `mysql`. You can change the ownership of the files with: `chown -R mysql /mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql/`. As you have Ubuntu, you might have errors caused by apparmor. If this is the case, run: `echo "alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql/," >> /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue by replacing the contents of `/var/lib/mysql/` on my local machine with the contents of `/mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql/` (from the server).

I then encountered an error whilst trying to start MySQL Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist which I solved by upgrading MySQL on my local machine and restarting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20262826/8231049

Now I'm able to dump the databases from my local machine :)

Edit: Can't accept my answer before waiting 2 days. Will do then.